# What error type should I use if someone inputs a integer where there should be a string in the answer?

Tags: python, error-handling, throw

I know how to raise the error type but I cannot figure out which error I should use if someone enters a integer into the string of `raw_input`.

Here is my code:

```
try:
    print "Welcome to my Quiz!"
    points = 0

    #Asks the user the first question and check to see if the answer is right and gives them a point if they are
    question1 = raw_input("Here's question #1! What is the name of Spongebob's pet?")

    if (question1.lower()) == "gary":
        print "You are correct!"
        points +=1
    else:
        print "You are wrong!"

    #Asks the user the second question and check to see if the answer is right and gives them a point if they are
    question2 = raw_input("Here's question #2! Whos is Spongebob's best friend?")

    if (question2.lower()) == "patrick":
        print "You are correct!"
        points +=1
    else:
        print "You are wrong!"

    #Asks the user the third question and check to see if the answer is right and gives them a point if they are
    question3 = raw_input("Here's question #3! Where does Spongebob work?")

    if (question3.lower()) == "krusty krab" or (question3.lower()) == "the krusty krab":
        print "You are correct!"
        points +=1
    else:
        print "You are wrong!"

    print "Thanks for playing my quiz! You got", points, "answers right out of 5! Nice job!"

except ValueError, errorvar:
    print errorvar

except NameError:
    print "Please enter a number for the correct variables, thanks"

except:
    print "An error has occurred"
```

Comment: This assignment must be due tomorrow, a lot of people are asking about it.

Answer (score 0):

[`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) always return a `str`. So if someone enters `123`, the result will be `'123'` (note the quotes).

In other cases where you somehow have a function that returns an `int` where the code expects a `str` (like how you called `lower` immediately on the result of `raw_input`), `int` would not have a `lower` method so trying to invoke that should result in an `AttributeError`.

```
>>> (0).lower()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'lower'
```